# Sending post data across different servers

Tags: php

I have a landing page on one server and main website is on another server is it possible to pass landing pages post values to the website on another server....?

Like if landing page has these fields:

first name
last name
email
phone

I want to collect this data and send it accross to the main website on another server. I would like to echo out the values from landing page to the corresponding fields on Main website

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that your more comfortable with PHP than curl, you can try sending that data over a socket connection. This should help!: http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php

If you go into more detail or put up some example code snippets, I may be of more help :p
Also if you need clarification on the sockets example, just ask

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have several options here.

1. Have the landing page on the main website and use `header('http://mainsite.com/landingpage.php')`.
2. Have the landing page send the values by GET. (`header('http://mainsite.com/landing?fname=John&lname=Doe&email=johndoe@mail.johndoesite.com&phone=555-555-5555')`
3. CMS ONLY! Have the landing page send a string of bootstrap data. (`mainsite.com/landing/john/doe/johndoe@johndoesite.com/555-555-5555`
4. You could store the data on a joint database and send the ID of the DB ROW by GET.
   ID would be sent by method in (2).
5. You could also send the data by sockets, e.g. `fsockopen()` + related functions